# Typescript configure mapping for compiled import path

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, yarn-workspaces

I have an aws amplify project which is using yarn workspaces.

My project has a lambda function and a layer. When the lambda function runs in aws it needs to import my library from the layer...

```
import MyLib from '/opt/nodejs/build/MyLib';
```

However when I run this function locally I want to import the library from my local file system

```
import MyLib from '/Users/sive/Documents/SWT/wake-book/amplify/backend/function/wakebookLayer/lib/nodejs/build/MyLib';
```

How can I tell typescript to compile an import from `/opt/nodejs/build/MyLib` to the location on my  local file system.

I tried using [path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) in my tsconfig.json

```
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "/opt/nodejs/build/MyLib": ["./amplify/backend/function/wakebookLayer/lib/nodejs/build/MyLib.d.ts"]
    },
```

This stops vscode complaining about an unknown import, so it is being 'linked' correctly (I can cmd click my import `/opt/nodejs/build/MyLib` path and I am taken to the full file system path.)

But the compiled js is still using the wrong path.

The compiled js file looks like this

`const MyLib_1 = __importDefault(require("/opt/nodejs/build/MyLib"));`

I would expect it to remap the import path and to look like this

`const MyLib_1 = __importDefault(require("/Users/sive/Documents/SWT/wake-book/amplify/backend/function/wakebookLayer/lib/nodejs/build/MyLib"));`

If I manually edit the output js to have the full file system path it works (I can run my project locally).

1. Have I misunderstood how path mapping is supposed to work?
2. Is there a way to get my desired behaviour?

Comment: TypeScript has supported [Dynamic Imports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#dynamic-import-expressions) since 2.4. This allows you to you can conditionally import other modules / libraries.

Comment: Oh nice. I was able to get [this](https://gist.github.com/ziggy6792/d5481c86a7a089eeaa1d1d577058e964) working.

But it still feels like a hack. I would rather do this at compile time than at runtime.

Also I don't like how I have to redefine the type for MyLib (line 7).

Answer (score 0):

Updated edit: I don't think this has anything to do with the fact that the path itself is long or complex. I'm having trouble getting mine to pass through correctly as well. I think the issue has to do more with how you're (and I'm) implementing the path mapping itself.

To test this theory, you could move one of those dependencies to a very simple, short path and see if that has any impact on the behavior at all.

Edit: I'm sorry, I just realized that you were trying to do this earlier and the problem seems to be related to the path itself... I'm not sure this will be helpful at all, but I'm going to leave it here for reference for now. I'm quite happy to try to address this with you over comments/edits.

What you are looking for is called "Path Mapping". There are a few ways this might be handled depending on your project. If you're deploying via SAM, this article from AWS describes one possible solution: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-aws-lambda-and-lambda-layers-in-aws-sam/

The important excerpt from that is here:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: sam app
Globals:
    Function:
        Timeout: 3
        Runtime: nodejs8.10

Resources:
    TempConversionFunction:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
        Properties:
            CodeUri: hello-world/
            Handler: app.lambdaHandler
            Events:
                HelloWorld:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /{conversion}/{value}
                        Method: get
```

> This change dropped out some comments and output parameters and
> updated the function resource to TempConversionFunction. The primary
> change is the Path: /{conversion}/{value} line. This enables you to
> use path mapping for our conversion type and value.

I've also seen examples that leverage tsconfig, but this seems to be a separate solution. Again, here is a link to the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

And the relevant excerpt:

> Sometimes modules are not directly located under baseUrl. For
> instance, an import to a module "jquery" would be translated at
> runtime to "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js". Loaders use
> a mapping configuration to map module names to files at run-time, see
> RequireJs documentation and SystemJS documentation.
>
> The TypeScript compiler supports the declaration of such mappings
> using paths property in tsconfig.json files. Here is an example for
> how to specify the paths property for jquery.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".", // This must be specified if "paths" is.
    "paths": {
      "jquery": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
    }
  }
}
```

Without knowing more about how you deploy your code, it's not possible for me to give more a more exact answer. But I hope this helps.

I should note, that your try/catch block does work, but it wouldn't be considered a best practice.

Answer (score -2):

It's been a year and a half since this post was first answered, and there still doesn't seem to be a widely publicized solution to this issue.

So in case anyone stumbles upon this, here's what I came up with:

I have a JAVASCRIPT (.js, not a .ts file) in all my lambda function handler directories whose single responsibility is to import the layer, at run time, from the appropriate path (at either the '/opt/nodejs' path or the local path on my computer).  It does so using a try/catch mechanism, which I know is a sort of anti-pattern, but it works well for this scenario.

```
  try{
      module.exports = require("/opt/nodejs/index")
  } catch { 
      module.exports = require("../../layer/index"); // my local path  
  }
```

Then, in my handler code I import the layer with this code snippet:

```
import layer = require("../../layer"); // path to aforementioned file
```

This solution is leveraging an obscure typescript feature referred to as 'export = syntax'

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require

It only works if the file that imports the switching layer code is a javascript (.js) file.  It doesn't work if it's a typescript (.ts) file.  So you'll also have to configure your tsconfig.json file with  `"allowJs": true`